# when i refresh, on receiving data with history.push with useEffect hook and the data is set to undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Base component:

```
const page = (e,index) => {
  console.log(e.img1)
    history.push({
      pathname: `${'/learning/tut_' + index}`,
      data: e.img1
    });
}
```

target component:

```
const ModeFiles = () => {
const location = useLocation();
const [img, setImg] = useSessionStorage('imgss', {});
useEffect(() => {  
    setImg(location.data);
    console.log(location.data)
});
return (
    <div>
        {/* {img.map(i => {
            return(
                <img src={i.src} alt="as" height="100" width="100" />
            )
        })} */}
    </div>
);
```

}

I m receiving the data in console but as i map the data in the return statement then it fails and in console also when i refresh the page the data is gone.

Comment: Try adding empty array at the end of useEffect like `useEffect(() => {...},[]);`

Comment: Try using localStorage instead of sessionStorage

Answer (score 0):

When the page is refeshed the sessionStorage data is lost as the session ends on refresh.Try to update the component state so the component is refreshed/Updated not the page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read How to Answer and consider to add some example code to your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer